# how to draw text with background color using canvas

Tags: android

I have some code where I'm drawing my text on bitmap (canvas)

```
canvas.drawTextOnPath(Text, textPath[count], gipa, -10, text);
```

Please tell me, it's possible to draw this text in path(textPath) with background color?

it's full function for drawing only text

```
 public void drawText(float x,float y ,String Text,Canvas canvas,Paint paint1 ,int count )
        {
            float xren =text.measureText(Text.trim());

            canvas.drawTextOnPath(Text, textPath[count], gipa, -10, text);

        }
```

Using this function I'm drawing text on my canvas. so how to modify this function for drawing this text with background?

Comment: You mean test should have a color or the canvas should have a color?

Comment: mmmm canvas have bitmap (image), on this image im drawing text using drawTextOnPath(because i need this funciton for drawing).. i want draw this text(green text color for example ) with background only for this text(example : black)

Comment: Can't you just draw the path with a line of your desired background color and then draw the text on it? This may require insetting the path a bit.

Comment: okay, can u provide some code how to draw line(or rectangle) on path with text ? please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely two steps are needed here.  you would draw a line along path first with color for background and then draw the text as indicated.  Set the thickness of the line with a paint object. Also, changing the style of the paint can help with the effect. try `FILL`, `STROKE` or `FILL_AND_STROKE` for different effects.

```
mpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mpaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
```

Added sample to draw a path(rectangle) with red color:

```
         Paint mPaint = new Paint();
         mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
         Path mPath = new Path();
         RectF mRectF = new RectF(20, 20, 240, 240);
         mPath.addRect(mRectF, Path.Direction.CCW);
         mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
         mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

Then draw text along same path (blue color):

```
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
         mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
         mPaint.setTextSize(20);
         canvas.drawTextOnPath("Draw the text, with origin at (x,y), using the specified paint, along the specified path.", mPath, 0, 5, mPaint);
```

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I ended up painting the text twice. First I used a stroke, then painted over it with the text. No calculations or heavy lifting.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to make like this then implement below code snippet:

[image]

```
     /**
     * PUT THIS METHOD FOR IMPLEMENT WATER-MARK IN COMMON FILE
     */
    public static Bitmap waterMark(Bitmap src, String watermark) {
        //get source image width and height
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Paint.FontMetrics fm = new Paint.FontMetrics();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.getFontMetrics(fm);
        int margin = 5;
        canvas.drawRect(50 - margin, 50 + fm.top - margin,
                50 + paint.measureText(watermark) + margin, 50 + fm.bottom
                        + margin, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawText(watermark, 50, 50, paint);
        return result;
    }
```

// To Get Bitmap from URI:

```
  private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(String photoPath) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

// Save Image :

```
 private String SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/shareImage");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image" + n + ".jpg";

        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

// Call like this :

```
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(attachment.get(i).getPath()); // Enter here your Image path

                Bitmap bitmapp = waterMark(bitmap, "ENTER YOUR TEXT FOR WATERMARK LABEL");

                String path = SaveImage(bitmapp);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

Here at last from uri you can get a new implemented watermark image.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this solution is better and more flexible than `drawPath`.

Use this to calculate the size of the text background:

```
private @NonNull Rect getTextBackgroundSize(float x, float y, @NonNull String text, @NonNull TextPaint paint) {
    Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = paint.getFontMetrics();
    float halfTextLength = paint.measureText(text) / 2 + 5;
    return new Rect((int) (x - halfTextLength), (int) (y + fontMetrics.top), (int) (x + halfTextLength), (int) (y + fontMetrics.bottom));
}
```

Then draw the background as a `Rect`:

```
Rect background = getTextBackgroundSize(x, y, text, textPaint);
canvas.drawRect(background, bkgPaint);
canvas.drawText(text, x, t, textPaint);
```

Comment: Simple and easy to adjust. Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the +5 and adjust the resulting rect with RectF.inset(...) after you created it to create the margins, which will give you better control.

Answer (score 1):

this method i created , it will give you better idea how easily you can do this

```
  public static Drawable getTextToDrawable(final String sText, final float    textSize, final int textColor, final int bgColor, final int imageSize) {

    Shape shape = new Shape() {

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
            paint.setTextSize(spToPixel(textSize));
            int ivImageSize = SUtils.dpToPx(imageSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
            int width = (int) (paint.measureText(sText)); // round
            int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent());
            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(ivImageSize, (int) (ivImageSize), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, ivImageSize, ivImageSize, paint);
            paint.setColor(bgColor);
            if (sText != null) {
                if (sText.length() < 3) {

                    canvas.drawCircle(ivImageSize / 2, ivImageSize / 2, ivImageSize / 2, paint);
                    paint.setColor(textColor);
                    canvas.drawText(sText, (ivImageSize - width) / 2, (height+baseline)/2, paint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, ivImageSize, height, paint);
                    paint.setColor(textColor);
                    canvas.drawText(sText, (ivImageSize - width) / 2, baseline, paint);

                }
            }
        }
    };
    return new ShapeDrawable(shape);
}
```