# How to draw a Spanned String with Canvas.drawText in Android

Tags: android, canvas, paint, drawtext, spannable

I want to draw a `SpannedString` to a `Canvas`.

[image]

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World!");
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, 1, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(backgroundSpan, 3, spannableString.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

The above example was drawn using a `TextView`, which in turn uses a `Layout` to draw text with spans. I know that [using a `Layout` is the recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870464/3681880) to draw text to the canvas. However, I am making my own text layout from scratch, so I need to implement this myself.

Doing something like this doesn't work

```
canvas.drawText(spannableString, 0, spannableString.length(), 0, 0, mTextPaint);
```

because `drawText` only gets the text from the `spannableString`, not any of the spans. The drawing colors are handled separately by `TextPaint`.

How do I use `canvas.drawText` (or `drawTextRun`) to draw the span information (specifically foreground and background color here)?

**Related**

- [How to loop through the spans in a SpannedString or SpannableString in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270575/how-to-loop-through-the-spans-in-a-spannedstring-or-spannablestring-in-android)
- [Is it possible to display multi-color text with one call to Canvas.drawText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410515/is-it-possible-to-display-multi-color-text-with-one-call-to-canvas-drawtext)

**Plan for a solution**

*I was going to directly do a self answer but this is turning out to be more difficult than I thought. So I will post first and then add an answer whenever I can figure it out. (I would of course welcome anyone to answer first.)*

Here are the pieces that I have so far:

- [Draw each span range as a separate text run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270576/3681880)
- Use [`drawTextRun`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextRun(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw the text ([examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.graphics.Canvas&method=drawTextRun)) (**update**: not added until API 23)
- Use [`getRunAdvance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getRunAdvance(char[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20int)) to measure where to start the next text run  (**update**: not added until API 23, use `measureText` instead)
- The background color will probably need to be drawn separately (with `drawRect` or maybe `drawPath`? See [here](https://azzits.wordpress.com/tag/android-drawtext-with-background-color/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242439/how-to-draw-text-with-background-color-using-canvas), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877417/android-draw-text-with-solid-background-onto-canvas-to-be-used-as-a-bitmap).)
- Source code for [`TextView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java), [`StaticLayout`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/StaticLayout.java), and [`TextLine`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/TextLine.java)

Comment: so what is the problem with `Layout#draw` actually?

Comment: @pskink, the standard `Layout` only handles LTR and RTL horizontal text. I am making a vertical text layout for [traditional Mongolian](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29739720/3681880). I've tried various [Layout hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29739721/3681880) in the past, but even those don't allow me to rotate emoji or CJK characters. So I am starting from scratch. [I have the basic layout functionality finished](https://github.com/suragch/mongol-library/blob/master/mongol-library/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/mongollibrary/MongolLayout.java); now I need to support spanned text.

Comment: ok, now i see it is not a "normal" `Hello World` you presented in your picture

Comment: so you want something like [this](http://pasteboard.co/8GVw7Cju.png)?

Comment: @pskink, that is correct. Although, for the purpose of this question, there is no need to worry about the vertical rotation or left to right line wrapping.

Comment: What you're asking is either vague or broad(..._"because `drawText` wants a `String`, not a `SpannableString`"_. It's because you're using too low level of the inheritance hierarchy, `Canvas.drawText()` takes `CharSequence` also, so it as polymorphic type for the `spannableString` variable. I used same approach in the sample to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android/32096884#32096884)... _"TextPaint should be setting things like the colors"_ It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Onik, You're right. I was using the wrong `drawText` method. I updated my question. The problem is that `drawText` still doesn't use the span information in the `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most people coming to this question, you should probably use a `StaticLayout` to draw your spanned text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410843/3681880) for help with that.

However, if you actually do need to draw the spanned text yourself, then you will need to [loop through all the spanned ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270576/3681880) and draw each one separately. You also need to measure the length of the text in each span so that you know where to start drawing the next span.

The code below handles `BackgroundColorSpan` and `ForegroundColorSpan`.

```
// set up the spanned string
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World!");
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, 1, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(backgroundSpan, 3, spannableString.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// draw each span one at a time
int next;
float xStart = 0;
float xEnd;
for (int i = 0; i < spannableString.length(); i = next) {

    // find the next span transition
    next = spannableString.nextSpanTransition(i, spannableString.length(), CharacterStyle.class);

    // measure the length of the span
    xEnd = xStart + mTextPaint.measureText(spannableString, i, next);

    // draw the highlight (background color) first
    BackgroundColorSpan[] bgSpans = spannableString.getSpans(i, next, BackgroundColorSpan.class);
    if (bgSpans.length > 0) {
        mHighlightPaint.setColor(bgSpans[0].getBackgroundColor());
        canvas.drawRect(xStart, mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().top, xEnd, mTextPaint.getFontMetrics().bottom, mHighlightPaint);
    }

    // draw the text with an optional foreground color
    ForegroundColorSpan[] fgSpans = spannableString.getSpans(i, next, ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    if (fgSpans.length > 0) {
        int saveColor = mTextPaint.getColor();
        mTextPaint.setColor(fgSpans[0].getForegroundColor());
        canvas.drawText(spannableString, i, next, xStart, 0, mTextPaint);
        mTextPaint.setColor(saveColor);
    } else {
        canvas.drawText(spannableString, i, next, xStart, 0, mTextPaint);
    }

    xStart = xEnd;
}
```

The top string in the image below was drawn with the code above. The bottom string was drawn with a regular `TextView` (which uses a `StaticLayout`).

[image]

Comment: You can handle most other spans the same way the foreground span is handled. In fact there is an update draw state method that will do it automatically. (I am just adding this as a comment for now because I can't remember the details off hand. If this is something you would like more info about then ask me about it and I will update this answer.)